# Error with Polyfit function Julia

Tags: julia

I sort of need to code in `julia` for my recently started Phd, and I'm having this error when trying to use the `polyfit` function from the `Polynomials` package which really bugs me :

```
DomainError

Stacktrace:
 [1] polyfit(::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Int64, ::Symbol) at /home/jrun/.julia/v0.6/Polynomials/src/Polynomials.jl:700 (repeats 2 times)
```

I tried all sorts of different kinds of testing, but keep getting it even with a code as simple as this :

```
Pkg.add("Polynomials")
using Polynomials

x = []
for i in 1:9
  append!(x, i)
end
y = [1,2,3,4,3,4,2,3,1]
polyfit(x, y)
```

Does anybody have an idea what that means ?

Thanks !

Comment: Where is the function `polyfit` from? Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please include a self-contained example in your question that we can reproduce ourselves. It is also worth putting the output of `versioninfo()` as the problems may be resulting from different version/platform combinations.

To answer your question, I will first run your code in my platform:

```
versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.6.3
Commit d55cadc350 (2018-05-28 20:20 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (NO_AFFINITY SANDYBRIDGE MAX_THREADS=8)
  LAPACK: liblapack
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)
```

The output of your code gives me:

```
Pkg.add("Polynomials")
using Polynomials

x = []
for i in 1:9
  append!(x, i)
end
y = [1,2,3,4,3,4,2,3,1]
polyfit(x, y)

ERROR: `float` not defined on abstractly-typed arrays; please convert to a more specific type
Stacktrace:
 [1] float at ./float.jl:848 [inlined]
 [2] polyfit(::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Int64, ::Symbol) at /home/aytekin/.julia/v0.6/Polynomials/src/Polynomials.jl:708
 [3] polyfit(::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Int64,1}) at /home/aytekin/.julia/v0.6/Polynomials/src/Polynomials.jl:700
 [4] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
```

The error results from the way you define your `x` variable. If you write `typeof(x)`, you will realize that it is `Array{Any,1}`. You are defining a 1-dimensional empty array of type `Any` when you write `x = []`. Then, you are appending values to it. Defining containers of abstract types (`Any` is the abstract type of which all `julia` types are subtypes) is not good for efficiency purposes. Moreover, appending to a vector the way you do is not a good practice, either. Apart from the efficiency issues, `x` should be a `Vector` of some `Number` type. In short, if you change your code to read as below:

```
x = collect(1:9)
typeof(x)
y = [1,2,3,4,3,4,2,3,1]
typeof(y)
p = polyfit(x, y)
```

You will probably see that your `x` and `y` variables are both `Vector`s of `Int64`. Moreover, you will obtain your polynomial.

Please read through the contents of [Julia Documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/). Especially useful would be the section [Noteworthy Differences from other Languages](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/noteworthy-differences/) if you are coming from one of those languages.

Comment: Correct, but the `polyfit` function can work a bit differently here to make this approach work (cf https://github.com/JuliaMath/Polynomials.jl/pull/142)

Comment: @jverzani, I have started a review with a comment under your PR.

Comment: Great. That wasn't my contribution, and my tweak is minor,  but it seems like there should be a more idiomatic manner to do this.